# is it possible to Plotly fill 'tomax'?

Tags: plotly, visualization, area, filled-area-plot

is it possible to fill plotly line chart to opposite of 'tozero'? like
this is fill: "tozero"
[image]

and this is what i want it to be like.
[image]

is there a way to fill: "tomax" ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add another trace which is a line segment with two points: `(start_time, max_fill_to_value), (end_time, max_fill_to_value)`, and use the argument `fill='tonexty'` which will then fill up to the other trace containing your timeseries data. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': pd.date_range(start='2023-10-01',end='2023-10-02',periods=48),
    'y': 10+np.random.rand(48)
})

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df['y']
))

max_fill_to_value = 5

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=['2023-10-01','2023-10-02'],
    y=[max_fill_to_value, max_fill_to_value],
    fill='tonexty', 
    mode='lines', 
    line_color='#636EFA',
    showlegend=False,
))

y_upper_range = max(df['y']) + (max(df['y'])-max_fill_to_value)/16
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[max_fill_to_value, y_upper_range])

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @krozero did this end up helping?